# Redirect Express default route to a new route

Tags: express, handlebars.js, feathersjs, express-handlebars

I have FeathersJS app (which is on top of Express) and I am using handlebars as templating engine.

I want to redirect the '/' of express to other URL but is keeps on loading the index.html in /public folder. My goal is to redirect it to a handlebars pages so that I can use the layout and don't repeat myself.

```
const path = require('path');
const favicon = require('serve-favicon');
const compress = require('compression');
const cors = require('cors');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const logger = require('winston');

const feathers = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration');
const express = require('@feathersjs/express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const socketio = require('@feathersjs/socketio');


const middleware = require('./middleware');
const services = require('./services');
const appHooks = require('./app.hooks');
const channels = require('./channels');

const app = express(feathers());

app.set('views', path.join(app.get('views')));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    extname: '.hbs',
    defaultLayout: 'main'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

// Load app configuration
app.configure(configuration());
// Enable CORS, security, compression, favicon and body parsing
app.use(cors());
app.use(helmet());
app.use(compress());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(express.static(app.get('public')));
// Host the public folder

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('test');
    res.redirect('/home');
});

app.get('/home', function(req, res, next){
    res.render('home');
});
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
    res.redirect('/');
});
app.get('/admin', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('admin',{});
});
app.get('/services', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('services',{});
});


// Set up Plugins and providers
app.configure(express.rest());
app.configure(socketio());

// Configure other middleware (see `middleware/index.js`)
app.configure(middleware);
// Set up our services (see `services/index.js`)
app.configure(services);
// Set up event channels (see channels.js)
app.configure(channels);

// Configure a middleware for 404s and the error handler
app.use(express.notFound());
app.use(express.errorHandler({ logger }));

app.hooks(appHooks);

module.exports = app;
```

It is not going to '/home' that I indicated. Am I missing something????

Thank you!

Comment: Could you show the whole file ?

Comment: @HamzaFatmi I updated my question.. at the app.get('/', fn)

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are using the `express.static` middleware **before** your `/` handler, since there is an `index.html` in the public folder, when you hit `/` it defaults to the index file, you can switch the order like this :

```
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(favicon(path.join(app.get('public'), 'favicon.ico')));

app.get('/', function(req, res){
console.log('test');
res.redirect('/home');
});

app.use(express.static(app.get('public')));
// Host the public folder

app.get('/home', function(req, res, next){
res.render('home');
});
app.get('/test', function(req, res, next){
res.redirect('/');
});
```